# How to shift column data using UPDATE in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I want to use a static-sized table like this:

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|  id  | col1     | col2      |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  1   | a        | x         |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  2   | b        | y         |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  3   | c        | z         |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to shift the column data upwards when I update [3, col1] for example? Table should look like this...

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|  id  | col1     | col2      |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  1   | b        | x         |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  2   | c        | y         |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  3   | d*       | z         |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

*New value in [row3, col1] and column data has been shifted up; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `update`/`join`:

```
update table t left join
       table tnext
       on t.id = tnext.id - 1
    set t.col1 = (case when tnext.id is null then 'd' else tnext.col1 end);
```

Comment: I hope you don't think of this as an obtuse request, but would you mind explaining the statement, so I can understand this join stuff, it befuddles my brain; if not, no worries.

Comment: This is not the forum for explaining how joins work.  Try google'ing or reading database documentation.